# Trying to reference earlier 'case' in a case statement

Tags: ruby, loops, case

When someone tries to update a value that is not currently stored in my hash, I would like to immediately refer back to `when 'add'` without restarting the entire `case` statement since I already know they want to add and don't want to prompt them again.

Is there a way to refer back to the `case choice` -> `when "add"` section of my code without restarting the entire `case` statement?

I know I could use nested `case` statements but I would rather not copy/paste identical code if I don't have to.

```
hash = {}
puts "Would you like to add or update this hash?"
choice = gets.chomp
case choice
when "add"
  puts "What key you like to add?"
  key = gets.chomp
  puts "With what value?"
  value = gets.chomp
  hash[key] = value
when "update"
  puts "Which key would you like to update?"
  key = gets.chomp
  if hash[key].nil?
  puts "Key not present, would you like to add it?"
    #here I would like the code that references back to "when 'add'" if the user types 'yes'
```

Sorry for the abrupt ending of the code. I didn't want to put in anything unnecessary to the solution.

Comment: consider a switch/case to be a revamped `if/elseif/elseif/../else` statement. only one block ever gets executed, and you can't jump around between the blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method/function that wraps the functionality inside that case. Then you can call that function from both places

```
hash = {}
def add_key
  puts "What key you like to add?"
  key = gets.chomp
  puts "With what value?"
  value = gets.chomp
  hash[key] = value
end 
puts "Would you like to add or update this hash?"
choice = gets.chomp
case choice
when "add"
  add_key
when "update"
  puts "Which key would you like to update?"
  key = gets.chomp
  if hash[key].nil?
    puts "Key not present, would you like to add it?"
    add_key
```

Comment: As is, this is a comment. Add a code example showing what you mean and it'll become an answer. Answers almost always contain code.

Comment: If the user wishes to update a key `key` that is not present, you say "Key not present, would you like to add it?" and then (without waiting for an answer) "What key would you like to add?". But wait, the user has already told you what the key is. Also, I'd use `unless hash.key?(key)` or `if !hash.key?(key)` instead of `if hash[key].nil?` in case `nil` is a key.  `has_key?` and `include?` are synonyms for `key?`.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a rush, and just used his code as is, replacing just the necessary bits to provide a starting point